# Insert into select from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In table1 is some changes opposite table2. I need get in to table3 only values which is missing in table1 opposite table2.

Table1

```
Column1
a
b

d
e

g
h
i
```

Table2

```
Column1
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table3]
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[table2]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM [dbo].[table1]
                      WHERE [dbo].[table2].column1 = [dbo].[table1].column1 
                        AND [dbo].[table2].column1 = [dbo].[table1].Pernr);
```

I get an error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I need :

Table3

```
Column1
c
f
```

Yesterday my script work but today is going wrong.. I do not know why?

Thanks for opinion

Comment: What's `.Pernr` and why you are comparing one column to 2 different columns in another table??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `insert` list the columns:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table3](column1)
    SELECT t2.column1
    FROM [dbo].[table2] t2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM [dbo].[table1] t1
                      WHERE t2.column1 = t1.column1
                     );
```

Of course, you can have more than one column for the insert.  Just list all of them in both the `insert` and the `select`.

I don't know what `Pernr`.  It is not part of your question.  You can, of course, add additional clauses to the `WHERE` clause in the subquery.

If `table3` does not exist, then use `select into` rather than `insert`:

```
    SELECT t2.*
    INTO table3
    FROM [dbo].[table2] t2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM [dbo].[table1] t1
                      WHERE t2.column1 = t1.column1
                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Column1 VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @Table1  VALUES ('a'),('b'),('d'),('e'),('g'),('h'),('i')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Column1 VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @Table2  VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f')


DECLARE @Table3 TABLE (Column1 VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @Table3 
SELECT 
*
FROM  @Table2 T2
WHERE T2.Column1 NOT IN
(SELECT Column1 FROM @Table1)

SELECT
* 
FROM @Table3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just "not in" - sub query as below

```
select * into #yourTable3 from #yourtable2 
    where column1 not in (select column1 from #yourtable1 where column1 is not null)
```

Your tables :

```
create table #yourtable1 (column1 varchar(10) )
insert into #yourtable1 (
Column1 ) values
 ('a')
,('b')
,(null )
,('d')
,('e')
, ( null )
,('g')
,('h')
,('i')

create table #yourtable2 (column1 varchar(10))
insert into #yourtable2 (column1 ) values
 ('a')
,('b')
,('c')
,('d')
,('e')
,('f')
```